# Cannot delete folder in Ubuntu in Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ubuntu, windows-10, atom-editor

I have a rails app in a folder in Ubuntu. I am using atom and git. I've always run git from the console, but last night I installed the hydrogen package on atom, so I can run git from atom. After this my app was a mess. I was trying to switch from one branch to another, but the files from one branch were transferred to the one that I had just switched to. I finally switched to master branch, which was supposed to have just the default files, but there were about 2000 files to commit. I tried to delete the folder but it doesn't work. Any suggestions about how to delete it, and some tips about using git on atom, when using Ubuntu?

```
$ ls -la 
 total 0 drwxrwxrwx 1 raluca raluca 4096 May 30 13:37
 . drwxrwxrwx 1 raluca raluca 4096 May 30 14:34 
 .. drwxrwxrwx 1 raluca raluca 4096 May 30 13:27
 app drwxrwxrwx 1 raluca raluca 4096 May 30 13:37
 db drwxrwxrwx 1 raluca raluca 4096 May 29 19:53
 public drwxrwxrwx 1 raluca raluca 4096 May 30 13:27
 test drwxrwxrwx 1 raluca raluca 4096 May 29 19:53 vendor
```

Comment: Can you update your post with 2 things? Open terminal and do "ls -la" add output to your post and do "git status" add the result here.

Comment: And what do you mean in "Ubutnu in Windows" ?

Comment: I have installed the linux subsystem for windows. sorry if I am not being clear enough, I have just started working with windows for few days.

Comment: Ok, so you are trying to right click delete the folder or trying to rm it from the terminal ?

Comment: So the folder is saved in a hidden file, among with the other linux files. I can acces it by going to C\whatever\folder_to_delete. when I go to this location I cannot delete it by right clicking. It sais I need to provide administrator permision

Comment: I am trying to post the result of the commands that you asked me for, but I don't know how to format the text.

Comment: append command with ">> <path>/out.txt" this will write stdout to the out.txt

Comment: To delete from ubuntu bash you need to do "rm -Rf <folder_path>" example "rm -Rf ./test" and for sudo "sudo rm -Rf ./test". You should also know there is no going back from this command.

Comment: I have uninstalled Ubunto.Files are still there...

Comment: Open cmd as admin then cd into the parent folder "RD /S /Q <folder_name>" Remove Directory /Subfolders /Q(Silent)

Comment: I get acees denied @KALALEX .

Comment: Using cmd as admin ?

Comment: Yes. I have also went into the file’s properties and tried to change the owner of the file, but it didn’t work either. Then I also tried to reinstall linux, but with no succes. Now I am resetting my windows. Thank you for your help. Even thou I didn’t solve the problem, I have learend a few things about windows on the way :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (using Ubuntu on Windows). I created a file that was in my home directory and I could not delete it either with Linux (sudo rm filename) or with Windows (del filename). I got permission denied on both.

The solution was to:

1. First use `chmod 777 ~`  granting any user permission to edit directory.
2. Then use `chown username filename`, so that your current username can delete the file.
3. If you run `rm filename` you will still get the permission denied error at this point. Therefore, to let your previous commands take effect you will need to shut down your computer.
4. Restart your computer and check the home directory with bash `ls`, the file should be gone. It was for me. However, it will probably have moved to a different directory on your computer (i.e. in your Windows C drive "home directory").
5. So open cmd as admin and run `dir "\filename*" /s` (You will see file is still on computer but moved to C:\Users\username. Navigate to that folder using cmd and type `dir`. You will see the file there.
6. Finally, in cmd type `del filename` to delete the file (no permission error). Or if it is a folder you want to delete use `rd foldername /s`. Type `dir` and you will see the file will be permanently deleted from your computer.

Answer (score -1):

Since the files aren't commited yet, try this out:

```
git clean -f -d
```

Comment: If there is no permition this is not going to work and if you do it as admin/super user it is going to change .git permitions and anything that it touches, which is bad.